# Initializing an array of strucuters with an array as an element of the structure in c

Tags: c, arrays, struct, init

My structure is defined as follows:

```
typedef struct simpleStruct {
    int a[2];
    int b;
    int c;
} simpleStruct;
```

I am trying to initialize it using the following:

```
simpleStruct simpleTable[] = {
    {.a[0]= 0, .a[1]= 1, .b = 2, .c = 3},
    {.a[0]= 4, .a[1]= 5, .b = 6, .c = 7},
};
```

The compiler is throwing an 'illegal initialization' error.

As per the C99 Spec this should be allowed through Designated Initializers (http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.2/gcc/Designated-Inits.html)

I have tried several other ways of initializing it and  found that this works:

```
simpleStruct simpleTable[] = {
    {.a = {0,1}, .b = 2, .c = 3},
    {.a = {4,5}, .b = 6, .c = 7},
};
```

I was wondering if anyone had any insight on why the first version did not work.

Thanks.

Comment: What compiler are you using? Your code compiles fine with `gcc`.

Comment: I don't see where in that page it says `.a[0]` should work? (It does say you can initialize an array of structs with `[0].a`)

Comment: @DanielKleinstein I'm using a PowerPC Complier with C99 Extensions enabled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a bug in your compiler.  The initializers are correct, multiple nested designators are allowed per the C Standard.  There is an example of this in section 6.7.9 Initialization of the latest version:

*EXAMPLE 11 Designators can be used to provide explicit initialization when unadorned initializer lists might be misunderstood:*

```
  struct { int a[3], b; } w[] =
        { [0].a = {1}, [1].a[0] = 2 };
```

Comment: looks like it is a compiler bug, guess ill just have to make do for now, thanks

Answer (score 0):

[image: Everything seems fine to me]

```
    #include<stdio.h>

    typedef struct simpleStruct {
        int a[2];
        int b;
        int c;
    } simpleStruct;

    int main()
    {
        simpleStruct anObj[]={{{23,30},40,39},{{20,90},20,19}};
        printf("%d, %d, %d, %d\n", anObj[0].a[0], anObj[0].a[1], anObj[0].b, anObj[0].c);
        printf("%d, %d, %d, %d\n", anObj[1].a[0], anObj[1].a[1], anObj[1].b, anObj[1].c);
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: I know that way will work, I mentioned it in my question.  My question was on why the other way didn't work.

Comment: Okay! I'll try.  
**But why try many ways to solve a problem?**

Comment: To learn new skills!  C is a never ending game for avid learners.